# bugs in kitchen

Tags: pest-control

We live in Nashville, Tennessee. There are these bugs which infested our whole kitchen and eating away at all the foods like flour, sugar, pulses and almost everything else. And they even bite us or at least we feel so when they touch us. we have no clue what these bugs are. Could anyone please suggest something to prevent and get rid of these bugs? Pics attached

[image: Bug picture 1]

[image: Bug Picture 2]

Answer (score 4):

I work with an extermination company. The pictures aren't that clear, but the first one seems to be a Confused Flour Beetle and I would imagine the second one is the same. The Confused Flour Beetle feeds on flour and grains but do not bite. The best way to eliminate them is to go through your pantry and throw out any infested items. The remaining items should be stores in zip lock or Tupper ware.

I hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Thank god it isn't the Coherent Flour Beetle or the house would have to be wrapped.